Can you stop right-indenting from going out of text box with TinyMCE?

In this example provided by TinyMCE it doesn't allow you to left/decrease indent if you're already against the left side. Which is good. But there is not same disable/block when going right/normal indent. You can right-indent the middle paragraph all the way off the page. Initially, as it gets squished to the right edge it expands down as expected.

But if you keep indenting it goes beyond the container and just keeps going right.

Adjusting things like overflow and wraps doesn't help because it affects the normal wrapping behavior that happens when users type - which is working correctly.
IDEALLY the button would become unusable like the left/decrease indent. But that doesn't happen. Is there any way to keep it in the container?
